# ls ~ / | rofi -show -dmenu does not work with shortcuts in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ls, dmenu

I am trying to run the ls ~ / | rofi -show -dmenu in a shortcut but it doesn't work, if I run it in terminal it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a .sh file with the command "ls ... etc rofi ..." and then in the shortcut command I ran `sh /home/yourusername/path/file.sh` it worked for me.
be careful not to put `~ or $HOME` doesn't seem to work properly.